# Forcing a field of an F# type to be null

Tags: f#, null, option-type

I understand well the benefit of `option`, but in this case, I want to avoid using `option` for performance reasons. `option` wraps a type in a class, which just means more work for the garbage collector -- and I want to avoid that.

In this case especially, I have multiple fields that are all `Some` under the same circumstances, but I don't want to put them in a tuple because, again, tuples are classes -- and puts additional stress on the GC. So I end up accessing `field.Value` -- which defeats the purpose of `option`.

So unless there's an optimization I don't know about that causes `option` types to be treated as references that are potentially null, I want to just use `null`. Is there a way that I can do that?

Edit: To expand on what I'm doing, I'm making a [bounding volume hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume_hierarchy), which is really a binary tree with data only at the leaf nodes. I'm implementing it as a class rather than as a discriminated union because keeping the items immutable isn't an option for performance reasons, and discriminated unions can't have `mutable` members, only `ref`s -- again, adding to GC pressure.

As silly as it is in a functional language, I may just end up doing each node type as an inheritance of a `Node` parent type. [Downcasting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.isinst.aspx) isn't exactly the fastest operation, but as far as XNA and WP7 are concerned, almost anything is better than angering the GC.

Comment: Are you sure the added GC stress actually matters in your case?

Comment: @svick Yes, unfortunately, it's for collision detection for an XNA game -- which means that it might eventually be running on WP7 or Xbox 360, which both have a one-generation GC.

Comment: "and puts additional stress on the GC." - have you measured this?

Comment: @Mitch No, but I have measured the effect that using a tuple in a particle system has on the GC. It's pretty ugly, even on x64 .NET 4. Switching to custom struct tuples drastically increases the number of particles I can simulate.

Comment: I can't quite follow what you're trying to do but there may be an approach besides a null or an option type.  Maybe you could detail your use case a bit more and we might be able to find a third approach.

Comment: @Onorio Edited my question to elaborate,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233197.aspx), if you decorate your type with the `[<AllowNullLiteral>]` attribute, you can then call `Unchecked.defaultof<T>()` to build a null for you.

That seems to be the only way within F# to do what you want. Otherwise, you could marshall out to another .net language and get nulls from there... but I'm guessing that is not what you want at all

Comment: That requires that consumer types are also marked `[<AllowNullLiteral>]`, but I guess that's better than nothing. 3 of my 4 fields can be null now -- left, right and parent nodes.

Comment: Actually, I believe you misread the documentation: use `[<AllowNullLiteral>]` on types you own to allow null as a proper value. Use `Unchecked.defaultof<T>()` to create null values of F# types which you don't own and otherwise don't permit null as a proper value (which means you also need to do things like `object.ReferenceEquals(x, null)` instead of `x = null` to work around compiler checks).

Comment: @Stephen Yeah, turns out all I needed was `Unchecked.defaultof<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

Now there are *Value Options* which may give you the best of both worlds

```
[<StructuralEquality; StructuralComparison>]
[<Struct>]
type ValueOption<'T> =
    | ValueNone
    | ValueSome of 'T
```

No class wrapping, and syntax semantics of `Option<'T>`

Comment: That's pretty cool. I was under the impression that struct DUs could only be single case. Do you happen to know what the memory representation of these things is like? It doesn't say [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/discriminated-unions#struct-discriminated-unions).